# Capturing the Cookies in ftl in magnolia EE

Tags: magnolia

I would like to capture the cookie information in my template (ftl). MgnlContext is available in templates as ctx. Is it convenient way out to predict the cookie information? If so, any sample code on how......

thanks,
MJ

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share with us what you have tried so far. We can't do your work for you...

Answer (score 1):

The `ctx` object is actually a `WebContext` (at least if you render your template as a part of a web page, and not e.g. as an e-mail template), so you can use

```
[#list ctx.request.cookies as cookie]
  [#-- do whatewer you need with the cookie --]
[/#list]
```

Comment: Thanks Jozef for the reply. Intention is not to render on the page, but to manage/use the cookie information behind.

Comment: You can obtain the `HttpServletResponse` from the context the same way, i.e. using the `ctx.response`, so, theoretically, you could also add a cookie by calling `ctx.response.addCookie(yourCookie)`. But you have to prepare `yourCoookie` elsewhere (e.g. in your model class), as there is no way to do `new Cookie("name", "value")` in Freemarker ([workaround](https://forums.magnolia-cms.com/forum/thread.html?threadId=0e96f3a7-d030-4d57-84c1-773667bf70f3)). Anyway, I would **strongly** recommend to do all the cookie manipulation in a model class, not in the template script.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the fact that when you have caching turned on for that page will the code only be executed once (no matter whether you use a model class or the freemarker solution).

Maybe think of doing your cookie manipulation somewhere early in the filter chain (e.g. in a custom filter).